# No focus input drag and drop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using a `jquery ui` drag and drop on a `li`. In this `li` I have a `div` and I dynamically adds an `input field`, the problem is that after I added my `input` I can't write in it. here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="ui-state-default" name="li_transit">
       info text <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>

$(function(){   
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        cancel: ":input"
    });

    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();

});
```

Comment: Could you setup a JSFiddle for this please? It'll be easier to work out what's going on

Comment: [Disabling text selection is bad. Don't use this.](http://api.jqueryui.com/disableselection/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe disableSelection is stopping you from selecting any inputs inside of the li. Perhaps try commenting that out and seeing if your problem persists.